# AWS (SSL Enabled) Load Balancer with Angular + Springboot Communication Issues

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, https, ssl-certificate

With `AWS EKS` Cluster, I am able to communicate between Angular pod & Springboot pod without SSL.

Now I am just trying it out by adding (requesting AWS to provide me new certificate) and then access Angular application from ALB, it is loading the web app.
But, Internal calls to Springboot is getting failed.
It is making calls Angular(HTTPS) -> Springboot(HTTP)

What Configuration I am missing here, can community help me.
Since I am not using `Ingress` controller, What I did is created to ALB (Application Load Balancer) each for `Angular-App` and `SpringBoot-App`, and single **ACM Certificate** I have applied to both this ALBs with `HTTPS` listeners

Here is how looks like on Browser
[image]

And SSL Enabled ALB of Springboot working too
[image]

I am having CORS enabled configuration as well in Spring-Boot App

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

@EnableWebMvc
public class CorsConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**").allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS");;
    }
}
```

**Angular App ALB**
[image]

**Springboot App ALB**
[image]

**Request Headers**
[image]

Comment: Can we see the response headers in browser when it is failing? And error in console?

Comment: @grekier Added screen shots, and FYR: 
Provisional headers are shown
Learn more
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
Referer: https://gikonnect.com/
sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="106", "Google Chrome";v="106", "Not;A=Brand";v="99"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36

Comment: I guess you also should have an error (or multiple) in the console. Can we see that as well?

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed that the certificate is wrong for `https://gikonnect-sb-alb-1237389246.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com/gkonnect/v1/get-all-countries`. Certificate is for `gikonnect.com`. That is your error. Angular will not accept doing https call to a URL with wrong certificate and doesn't like either to do calls to http when running on htps.

I see 2 options here:

- update certificate add add the gikonnect-sb-alb-1237389246.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com name to it
- fix routing so that you can call `https://gikonnect.com/gkonnect/v1/get-all-countries` or similar. As long as the hostname is this one, the path might vary to simplify setup in AWS

Comment: is there any ways available that I will keep FQDN name different , and then forcefully call to the target service ? because Update certificate I am facing lot of challenges in AWS. it is not allowing me to add another certs.

Comment: Yes. As mentioned, fix routing in AWS. Not sure how yours is set up but maybe you will need to add an API gateway in front or similar. Really depends on your URL mapping setup.